# R Dplyr sub-setting

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I need to calculate `min`, `max` and `mean` by customer after sub-setting the population for primary contacts. To do this, I need to drop observations within a customer group if `contact == relation` and `amount < 25`. But, the tricky part is: if `contact == relation` and `amount == amount`, I need to keep both observations regardless the amount (this accounts for ties where we cannot define the primary contact).

If `contact == relation`, one can think of this as a household.
Each customer can be comprised of multiple households, so I've included contacts with `NULL` relationship values.

**Sample Data**

```
customer <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
contact <- c(1234,2345,3456,4567,5678,6789,7890,8901,9012,1236,2346)
relationship <- c(2345,1234,"","",6789,5678,"",9012,8901,2346,1236)
amount <- c(26,22,40,12,15,15,70,35,15,25,25)
score <- c(500,300,700,600,400,600,700,650,300,600,700)
creditinfoaggtestdata1 <- data.frame(customer,contact,relationship,amount,score)
```

**Expected Outcome**

[image]

As a point of reference, if I do not drop the appropriate contacts prior to calculating `min`, `max` and `mean`, by customer, I get an output table as follows:

[image]

Comment: in the second sentence of the first paragraph, what do you mean with `amount == amount`?

Comment: good question if you look at contact 5678 and 6789 both have amount = 15 considered a tie neither contact is a primary, contact 5678 has relationship 6789 and contact 6789 has relationship 5678 - they are in the same household like a spousal relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the requirement "contact = relation and amount = amount" means across different rows within the same customer group. Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
# Create a contact-relationship id where direction doesn't matter
df <- creditinfoaggtestdata1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(id = paste0(min(contact, relationship), max(contact, relationship))) 

# Filter new ID's where duplicates in amounts exist per customer group
dups <- df %>% 
  group_by(customer, id, amount) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  filter(count > 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(customer, id)

# User inner join to only select contact-relationship combinations from above
a <- df %>% 
  filter(amount < 25) %>% 
  inner_join(dups, by=c("customer", "id"))

# Combine with >= 25 data
b <- df %>% 
  filter(amount >= 25)

c <- rbind(a, b)

c %>% 
  group_by(customer) %>% 
  summarise(min_score = min(score), max_score = max(score), avg_score = mean(score))

Output:
  customer min_score max_score avg_score
     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1        1       500       700      600 
2        2       400       700      567.
3        3       600       700      650
```